# "Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context" compiling error when trying to encrypt file in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to encrypt a file in Kotlin, based on a [java tutorial](https://javapapers.com/java/java-file-encryption-decryption-using-password-based-encryption-pbe/). And I'm currently unable to convert this to Kotlin because Kotlin doesn't support assignments inside a while loop context.

Here's the code I'm trying to convert:

```
byte[] input = new byte[64];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = inFile.read(input)) != -1) {
    byte[] output = cipher.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
    if (output != null)
        outFile.write(output);
}
```

How do I proceed?

Comment: I probably don't know what I'm talking about, but it sounds like Kotlin doesn't support the Java-style *assignment operator `=` returns the value just assigned* in an expression context. You may have to assign `bytesRead` at the end of the loop and just keep `while(bytesRead != -1)`

Comment: I ended up using `while (fis.read(input).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) { ... }`.